# How can I solve this problem with run spring boot test code?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, gradle

This is my test code in spring boot.

```
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.servlet.WebMvcTest;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringRunner;
import org.springframework.test.web.servlet.MockMvc;
import org.springframework.test.web.servlet.ResultActions;

import static org.springframework.test.web.servlet.request.MockMvcRequestBuilders.get;
import static org.springframework.test.web.servlet.result.MockMvcResultMatchers.content;
import static org.springframework.test.web.servlet.result.MockMvcResultMatchers.status;

import com.myname.pjt.springboot.web.HelloController;

@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@WebMvcTest(controllers = HelloController.class)
public class HelloControllerTest {

    @Autowired
    private MockMvc mvc;

    @Test
    public void hello_will_return() throws Exception {
        String hello = "hello";
        mvc.perform(get("/hello")).andExpect(status().isOk()).andExpect(content().string(hello));
    }
}
```

And this is error message.

```
Testing started at 9:34 PM ...

> Task :compileJava UP-TO-DATE
> Task :processResources NO-SOURCE
> Task :classes UP-TO-DATE
> Task :compileTestJava
> Task :processTestResources NO-SOURCE
> Task :testClasses
> Task :test FAILED
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':test'.
> No tests found for given includes: [com.myname.test.springboot.web.HelloControllerTest.hello_will_return](filter.includeTestsMatching)
* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 7.0.
Use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings.
See https://docs.gradle.org/6.3/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings
BUILD FAILED in 1s
3 actionable tasks: 2 executed, 1 up-to-date
```

I don't know how to solve this problem...

I tried these.

1. Changed Settings > Build, Execution, Deployment > Build Tools > Gradle > Run test using > Changed "Gradle (Default)" to "IntelliJ IDEA"
2. Add `secure = false` in `@WebMvcTest`

-> `@WebMvcTest(controllers = HelloController.class)` to `@WebMvcTest(controllers = {HelloController.class}, secure = false)`

But it does not still work...
Please help me...

Also this is my `build.gradle`.

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        springBootVersion = '2.1.7.RELEASE'
    }
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:${springBootVersion}")
    }
}

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'eclipse'
apply plugin: 'org.springframework.boot'
apply plugin: 'io.spring.dependency-management'

group 'com.myname.pjt'
version '1.0-SNAPSHOT'
sourceCompatibility = 1.8

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    jcenter()
}

dependencies {
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web')
    testCompile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test')
}
```

Comment: Please explain it with further details

Comment: just press the green button next to `public class HelloControllerTest`, if still doesnt work please show your gradle build file

Comment: Oh, I missed it. I'm sorry but it's my first time using stackoverflow.
I pressed the green button next to ```public class HelloControllerTest``` and I got that error.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are running your test using JUnit 5, but declare your test using a JUnit 4 annotation (`org.junit.Test` vs. `org.junit.jupiter.api.Test`) and that's why it isn't picking up on your test.

Comment: I'm really sorry but it's my first time using gradle. How can I know what I'm using now? JUnit4 or JUnit5?